# Integral at infinity

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, analysis, improper-integrals

Let us fix a parameter $s \in \left(\, 0,1\,\right)$, the problem is to compute, or at least study the convergence, the following integral
$$
I =
\int_{2}^{\infty}\left[\frac{1 - x^{s}}{\left(x - 1\right)^{1 + s}} +
\frac{x^{s} + 1}{\left(1 + x\right)^{1 + s}}\right]\mathrm{d}x
$$
It seems to be quite easy to prove that 
$$
I\leq C \int_{2}^{\infty}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x^{1 + s}}
$$
for some positive constant $C > 0$, but the problem is to prove a lower bound.

Comment: Correct me if Im wrong, but your function is non-negative everywhere. Since you have bounded your integral with the one which converges - your integral converges too.

Comment: Actually i don't think that the function is non-negative everywhere since the two terms in the integral are the first negative and the second positive.

Comment: How tight bounds would you like to have? The $\dfrac{1}{(x\pm 1)^{1+s}}$ parts can be easily evaluated, and it remains to look at the integral of $x^s\bigl((x-1)^{-1-s} - (x+1)^{-1-s}\bigr)$. Coarse estimates for that are easy. If you want tighter bounds, some more work is required.